# label those partitions (in your partition.xml file)

Tags: android, qualcomm

Currently I am analysing partition.xml file in AndroidGo(nhlos) (chipset msm8909). I want to know what are the utilities of below parameters:
1) partition label
2) size in kb
3) type
4) bootable
5) readonly

For example:

Please let me know , so that it will be helpful.

Comment: I don't think you'll get the answer to this here StackOverflow is for programming maybe try asking this in other SE community.